# Need a safe way to execute external code

Tags: php

I was wondering if it was possible to allow people to write and execute PHP code from my website without the use of "eval" due to risks.
I have googled around and I did find some answers, just not the answers I was looking for (call_user_func).
This is not what I am looking for as it does not allow people to run a full PHP script.

It's a small group of people executing it so server load will not be an issue.

edit 1: Users should not be able to corrup/delete files;
Users should be able to create complete scripts.;
Users should be able to run html code but trigger php as soon as php tags are used.

Comment: The risk of `eval` _is_ arbitrary code. If you're not worried or bothered about running possible dangerous scripts, `eval` is fine.

Comment: Alternatively there is [PHP Sandbox](https://github.com/fieryprophet/php-sandbox) which whitelists acceptable code.

Comment: Define "safe". What does this tool need to be safe against — does it need to resist deliberate malicious use?

Comment: It has to be safe as in, unable to delete files or corrupt anything Edit: people need to be able to create a whole php script instead of just one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own wrapper process around php that uses `ptrace` to control the execution of the child php process to prevent it from opening file handles, connecting to the network, etc.

That way, even if people decide to try using malicious code in eval, the system calls will be blocked on the native level.

Comment: Ptrace is a linux command?

Comment: You'd write a native wrapper around the php process using a combination of ptrace, fork and execv to start the php process in a secured environment. Probably you'd write this in C or some other native language.

Comment: I'll check on that later, not too familiar with other languages :)

Comment: This is a useful answer. It's wrong to attempt to solve the problem at the language level.

Comment: Agreed, i'll probably end up creating a virtual machine to run the code